# NullPointerExceptions not being thrown in test

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception

I have just installed EclEmma into my Eclipse setup and run it against a test suite to see what code coverage I had on its target methods.

I have found that any lines where I throw a new `NullPointerException` are not covered, despite asserting in the test that one will be thrown when the method is invoked. I am finding that these tests pass!

An example can be found below:

```
public static boolean isXMLFile(File f) {

   if(f==null) {
     throw new NullPointerException("isXMLFile: Input File must not be null");
   }
}
```

I am finding that I am getting the NPE I wanted when I call the above code with `isXMLFile(null)` in my jUnit test, but I don't think it is coming from where I think it is!

I'm missing something very fundamental about runtime exceptions, aren't I?

Comment: Throwing `NullPointerException` manually is usually a bad idea, consider throwing `IllegalArgumentException` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you dumpt the stacktrace of the exception, you'll see exactly where it's coming from.

That said -- you probably don't want to be throwing a null pointer exception, you probably want to be throwing an illegal argument exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you use f anywhere and f is null that exception will be thrown anyways

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. With your advice I have figured it out!

The above portion of code was part of a larger 'If' block and the test for Null was second in the list. First in the list was a String equals test on the value coming in - ergo a NullPointer on the String method.

Moved my test for null to the top of the tree and hey presto, the stack trace originates from where I would like it to.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to track the origin of exceptions is to manually enter a slightly different message for each one. You'll be able to see those quite clearly with a standard debugger.